# Replace values from a column based on other 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following table:

```
Name1    Name   ID
123      Stefi  123   
Giorgi   Giorgi 858
211      Mara   211
Giorgi   Ana    333
Otto
Anna
```

The problem is that on the column Name1 I have both Name and Id and I need to have only the name. Based on the columns Name and Id I have to extract the wrong information from Name1 and replace with the name. Columns "Name" and "Id" can be seen as a separate table from where to extract information for the first column

At the end, the table should look like this

```
Name1    Name   ID
Stefi    Stefi  123   
Ana      Ana    333
Giorgi   Giorgi 858
Mara     Mara   211
Giorgi   
Otto
Anna
```

Any idea how I can fix this problem? Maybe with Index? Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with just copying data of column `Name` into `Name1`? Where is the issue here?

Comment: The problem is that i have tousands of names. Column Name1 may have dulicates, but this is not a problem.

Comment: you can copy over the whole column from `Stefi` to `Mara` at once by just selecting the range, copy it and paste it into the first column

Comment: Yes, but if the order is of the 3 column is different. And the first column (Name 1) has 1000 names, and the column 2 and 3 only 300 because the first column can contain duplicates

Comment: Did you try with the `Index` and `Match` formulas in combination? they would work to lookup your data.

Comment: Yes, something like this but is not working =INDEX($A$31805:$A$32275;MATCH(C2;$C$31805:$C$32275;0);1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH` to get the result shown in column E `Complete`

- Office 2013 or later use

  ```
  =IFNA(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(A:A,C:C,0)),A:A)
  ```
- Office 2010 use

  ```
  =IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(A:A,C:C,0)),A:A)
  ```

[image]

Comment: I get #NAME? Maybe because I have Excel2010?

Comment: "This formula contains unrecognized text". It's identical. If i go by reference: IFNA is underlined

Comment: Meh my bad, `IFNA` was introduced in Office 2013. See my edit.